# Limits for a bottleneck

Tags: objective-functions, autoencoders, pytorch

I have some 64x64 pixels frames from a (simulated) video, with a spaceship moving on a fixed background. The spaceship moves in a straight line with constant velocity from left to right (along the x-axis), and the frames are from equal time intervals.  I can also place the ship at different y positions and let it move. In total I have 8 y positions and 64 frames for each y position (the details don't matter that much). Intuitively, as the background is fixed, and the shape of the ship is the same, all the information to reconstruct the image is found in the x and y position of the spaceship. What I am trying to do is to have a NN with an encoded and a decoder and a bottleneck in the middle and I want that bottleneck to have just 2 neurons. Ideally, the network would learn in these 2 neurons some function of x and y in the encoder, and the decoder would invert that function to give the original image. Here is my NN architecture (in Pytorch):

```
class Rocket_E_NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 4, 2, 1),          # B,  32, 32, 32
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 4, 2, 1),          # B,  32, 16, 16
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 4, 2, 1),          # B,  64,  8,  8
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 4, 2, 1),          # B,  64,  4,  4
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 256, 4, 1),            # B, 256,  1,  1
            nn.ReLU(True),
            View((-1, 256*1*1)),                 # B, 256
            nn.Linear(256, 2),             # B, 1
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        z = self.encoder(x)
        return z

class Rocket_D_NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2, 256),               # B, 256
            View((-1, 256, 1, 1)),               # B, 256,  1,  1
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 64, 4),      # B,  64,  4,  4
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 64, 4, 2, 1), # B,  64,  8,  8
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 4, 2, 1), # B,  32, 16, 16
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 32, 4, 2, 1), # B,  32, 32, 32
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 3, 4, 2, 1),  # B, 3, 64, 64
        )

    def forward(self, z):
        x = self.decoder(z)
        return x
```

And this is the example of one of the images that I have (it was much higher resolution but I brought it down to 64x64):

[image]

So after training it for around 2000 epoch with a bs of 128, with Adam, trying several LR schedules (going from 1e-3 to 1e-6) I can't get the loss below an RMSE of 0.010-0.015 (the pixel values are between 0 and 1). The reconstructed image looks ok by eye, but I would need a better loss for the purpose of my project. Is there any way I can push the loss lower, or am I asking too much from the NN to distill all the information in these 2 numbers?